# Power sets of union (intersection) and union (intersection) of power sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be the universal set, $A,B\subseteq U$.

Corrected due to my mistakes detected in comments. 
This works only for finite sets.

Prove these statements:

$\mathcal P(A\cup B)\;\supseteq\; \mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)$

$\mathcal P(A\cap B)\;=\; \mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)$

explanation by cardinality:
$$|\mathcal P(A\cup B)|\;=\;2\;^{|A|\;+\;|B|\;-\;|A\cap B|}$$
$$\;\;\;\;|\mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)|\;=\;2\;^{|A|}+2\;^{|B|}-2\;^{|A\cap B|}$$
$$|\mathcal P(A\cup B)|\;\geq\;|\mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)|$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;|\mathcal P(A\cap B)|\;=\;|\mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)|\;=\;2\;^{|A\cap B|}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The fact that two sets have the same cardinality does not mean that the two sets are the same set; consider e.g. $\mathbb N, \mathbb Z$.

Comment: So, since $|\Bbb{N}| = |\Bbb{Z}|$, you would conclude that $\mathcal P(\Bbb{N}) = \mathcal P(\Bbb{Z})$?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb{N} \subseteq \Bbb{Z}$, so $\mathcal{\Bbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{\Bbb{Z}}$. The two sets have the same cardinality, but you cannot conclude that they are equal.

Comment: A universal set $U$ does not have cardinality larger than its subsets since $U\subseteq U$. The *power set* of a set, be that set infinite or finite, always has strictly larger cardinality.

Comment: The universal set, understood as the set containing *everything*, is not allowed in standard set theory (standard here means Zermelo–Fraenkel). However, an universal set in the context of this problem (and, I suspect, your lectures, since I took the same courses some 15 years ago), is an arbitrary but concrete set $U$ that we choose, e.g. $U=\mathbb C$ or $U=\{2,5,7\}$ (or we keep it abstract) and then preform set algebra on its subsets. So, these are separate concepts, but not completely unrelated.

Comment: @GoranMalic Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof isn't correct : if $X$ is an infinite set, you can **always** find a proper subset of $X$ which has the same cardinality as $X$.

All you need to use is the definition of the power set : $$X \in \mathcal{P}(S) \Longleftrightarrow X \subseteq S$$

proof of $\mathcal P(A\cup B)\;\supseteq\; \mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)$ :

> Let $X \in \mathcal P(A)\cup \mathcal P(B)$,
>   If $X \in
> > \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $X \subseteq A$, hence $X \subseteq A \cup B$
>   whence $X \in \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$.
>   Likewise, if $X\in
> > \mathcal{P}(B)$, then $X \in \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$.

proof of $\mathcal P(A\cap B)\;=\; \mathcal P(A)\cap \mathcal P(B)$:

> - "$\subseteq$" : Let $X\in \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$ ie $X \subseteq A \cap B$. Then $X\subseteq A$ (ie $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$) and
>     $X\subseteq B$ (ie $X \in \mathcal{P}(B)$). Hence, $X \in
>    \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$.
> - "$\supseteq$" : Let $X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)$, that is to say $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ (ie $X \subseteq A$) and $X \in
>    \mathcal{P}(B)$ (ie $X \subseteq B$). We hence have $X\subseteq A \cap
>    B$, in other words $X \in \mathcal{P}(A\cap B)$.

Comment: But if I have a universal set, it must have a higher cardinality than $A, B$. If I take infinite sets, then, as far as I'm concerned, $\mathbb R$ should be the universal set. But thanks for the correction. I wasn't precise and I made a mistake. Better now, than on exam.